# Grails 3 schemaExport contains warning with FileNotFoundException that looks for sitemesh.xml

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

When **schemaExport** is executed using Gradle for a Grails 3.3 application, below warning is in the log though **ddl.sql** is created. According to Grails 3 documentation sitemesh.xml is removed so naturally the file wouldn't be available. Am I missing something?

*Tools and version: Grails 3.3.0, Gradle 3.3, Hibnerate 5, Sybase ASE 15.7*

```
2017-09-13 12:50:45.264  WARN --- [           main] o.s.mock.web.MockServletContext          : Couldn't determine real path of resource class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml]

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:49)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.getRealPath(MockServletContext.java:458)
        at org.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.<init>(Grails5535Factory.java:78)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.view.SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.loadSitemeshConfig(SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.java:105)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.view.SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.init(SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.java:67)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.view.SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.onApplicationEvent(SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.java:146)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.view.SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.onApplicationEvent(SitemeshLayoutViewResolver.java:42)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.ui.command.GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner.run(GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner.groovy:55)
        at grails.ui.command.GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner.main(GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner.groovy:102)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a WARN message. The underlying spring class is looking for it and just saying it's not there. The default the log level does not show this output.

You can safely ignore the message or adjust your logger to not show it.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.java#L460

Comment: Since the command was anyway generating the ddl.sql file I am kind of ignoring it. But seems bit weird since the file was not supposed to be available from Grails 3. Shouldn't the check be removed as well by default?

Comment: Grails is built on the spring-framework (and other frameworks). I'm not sure why spring would remove an warn message for some feature grails doesn't use as other spring-framework users likely do use it.

Comment: It's most likely that Spring is looking for specific resources based on configuration. I am not sure why Grails can't configure Spring not to look for Sitemesh.